# Setting body id for custom post types in Wordpress

Tags: wordpress, custom-post-type

I have developed a function in `functions.php` to add a specific id to the body tag depending on the page template or the parent page template if it's a child page.

```
function get_body_id() {

    global $post;
    $parents = get_post_ancestors( $post->ID );
    $parent_id = ($parents) ? $parents[count($parents)-1]: $post->ID;

    $temp = get_page_template_slug($parent_id);
    $path = pathinfo($temp);
    $temp = $path['filename'];

    switch ( $temp ):
        case 'page-recipe-landing':
            $id = 'bg-green';
            break;

        case 'page-home':
        default:
            $id = 'bg-pink';
            break;
    endswitch;

    echo "id='".$id."'";
}
```

This works well for pages and their children but for my custom post types  events/news and recipes this obviously will not return anything for `get_post_ancestors( $post->ID )`.

Is there a way to alter my function to cater for these custom post types or to assign custom post types to a specific 'page'?

Thanks for help with this.

Answer (score 0):

```
<?php
    if(empty($parents)) {
        $loop = new WP_Query(array('post_type' => 'NAME_OF_TYPE', 'post_status' => 'publish'));
        while($loop->have_posts()): $loop->the_post();
            the_ID();
        endwhile;
    }
?>
```

This code should at least output the ID of each post with a custom type of `NAME_OF_TYPE`.  If you wanted to store those in an array and work with them from there, the premise would be pretty much the same.  I haven't tested the code, but it should work with custom post types.